Blazor MAUI Windows upgrade to .NET 9 nuget error
We have just started to update our Blazor MAUI app to .NET9. We are getting a strange error when compiling for Windows (same code works for Android).
error NU1102: Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.win-x64 with version (= 9.0.0)
error NU1102:   - Found 102 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 9.0.0-preview.7.24405.7 ]
error NU1102:   - Found 0 version(s) in C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\library-packs
error NU1102:   - Found 0 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
error NU1102: Unable to find package Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref with version (= 9.0.0)
error NU1102:   - Found 347 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 10.0.17763.1-preview ]
error NU1102:   - Found 0 version(s) in C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\library-packs
error NU1102:   - Found 0 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages

Stuck on what this issue means and what I am missing, we are building on windows-latest on Azure Pipelines. Using .NET 9.0.101.

Did you follow the lengthy guide to change everything needed? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/whats-new/dotnet-9?view=net-maui-9.0

Been looking in this guide but can't find anything that I can see causes or resolves this issue?

I can't find any package that is actually using Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.win-x64


.NET 9 changed quite a lot so you shouldn't expect merely updating some version numbers in your old projects can finish the upgrade. The lengthy guide shows quite a few steps under "Upgrade from .NET 8 to .NET 9" that need to be taken. 2) If you create a .NET 9 Blazor/MAUI app from the new templates, you might get another way out.


@LexLi, did you actually build a MAUI app for .NET 9? I am getting the same error for a new MAUI app created from a template for .NET 9 without any changes. The issue occurs when you use a RuntimeIdentifier in the build (for example, with the parameters "/p:Platform=x86 /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x86"). The guide for upgrading from .NET 8 to .NET 9 you are referencing is not lengthy at all and is very straightforward. Most of the things listed there are not applicable to most apps. So, for most apps, the upgrade is as simple as changing the target frameworks. So, your advice is not useful.

@Michael I did compile and publish MAUI/Blazor test apps with .NET 9. But until you kindly revealed the command line arguments, I wasn't able to reproduce the error. Now I can see why that error message appears and an answer has been provided below.

If you use the latest .NET 9 MAUI Blazor template to create the test project, the way to produce Windows 10+ x64 builds are
msbuild /t:restore /p:TargetFramework=net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0 /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win10-x64
msbuild /t:publish /p:TargetFramework=net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0 /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win10-x64 /p:SelfContained=True


Change to win10-x86 if you want to build x86 bits.

Note that,

Without /p:SelfContained=True, the produced artifacts will require .NET 9 desktop runtime to be installed separately on the target machine.
Microsoft Edge WebView 2 runtime is not included in the artifacts, so that runtime needs to be downloaded and installed separately on the target machine.


According to GitHub discussions like this one, the primary deployment method should be MSIX packages, so the steps (like explicitly selecting win-x64 or win-x86) for console/ASP.NET Core web apps aren’t applicable to MAUI.
And if you configure your MAUI application to create a Windows MSIX package, then you can fine-tune the publishing settings in a .pubxml file and then use MSBuild to automate the steps.
There is a .NET 9 breaking change that directly leads to the error itself.

